# Collect data of all select/resize/drop events - fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to collect data (event start, event end) of all `select` events (also `resize` and `drop` if triggered) from fullcalendar plugin (`agendaWeek` view) to handle it later in PHP.

I tried to do something like this:

```
select: function(start, end) {
    var start = moment(start).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
    var end = moment(end).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");

    $('.some_start').val(start);
    $('.some_end').val(end);
},
eventResize: function(event) {
    $('.some_start').val(event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
    $('.some_end').val(event.end.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
},
eventDrop: function(event) {
    $('.some_start').val(event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
    $('.some_end').val(event.end.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
}
```

But it obviously overwrites input fileds after each event.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: If you want to collect data, you should push the data you want into an array - as I read your code, all you do is set some dom elements value.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Could you show me example of how to do that?

Comment: Var endarray = []; myarray.push (event.end); - you should try googling around a bit

Comment: Hm. I just realized how bad I expressed previous question. I Know how to use arrays in js. It's just there is no automatically returend id or some unique index ( after each of events ) which i could store in array . I found out that id is optional and i need to manage it by mine self

Comment: All fullcalendar events has a unique id :) - its "event._id"

Comment: Thast's true but its also prefixed with a string, something like `"_fs1","_fs2"`.. Sure I can use `substring` to get only number but anyway `event._id` is returned only for resize, drop events - not for select event which is used in the first place

Comment: Im pretty sure i use it to delete selected events.  Ill check

Comment: By select event I men `select: function(start, end, allDay)` not some other event on already selected area